# Confidence regions on bivariate normal distributions using $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}$ or $\mathbf{S}$

Tags: normal-distribution, confidence-interval, maximum-likelihood, multivariate-analysis, hotelling-t2

Given a $5 \times 2$ dataset $\mathbf{X} =\left( \begin{array}{rr}-0.9&0.2\\2.4&0.7\\-1.4&1.0\\2.9&-0.5\\2.0&-1.0 \end{array} \right)$. Assume that $X\sim N_2(\mu, \Sigma)$.

Using $\hat{\mu}_{MLE}$ and $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}$, I need to calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and draw an 80% probability ellipse. In the statistical books I've seen, it is usually stated that to draw such an ellipse, you use $\mathbf{S} = \frac{1}{n-1}\sum(\mathbf{x_j} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})(\mathbf{x_j} - \mathbf{\bar{x}})'$ and calculate the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for this matrix. Then you can draw the ellipse, using these eigenvectors and the calculated $\mathbf{\bar{x}}$.

**My Question**
 Now I now that $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE} = \frac{n-1}{n}\mathbf{S}$. So what do I need to do here? Is it correct to use  $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}$ to calculate the eigenvalues and -vectors and use them to find the 80% confidence interval, or do you always need to use $\mathbf{S}$?

Comment: If no one forces me to use $\hat{\Sigma}_{MLE}$, I will use $S$, because $S$ is unbiased estimate of $\Sigma$.

Comment: I see that posting the question here worked better to generate some response :-)

Comment: Is what you want an ellipse that contains $X$ with 80% probability under the assumption that the true parameter values equals the MLEs?  Or do you perhaps want an 80% https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confidence_region for the unknown mean vector $\mu$?

Comment: @JarleTufto An ellipse that contains $X$ with 80% probability. I believe that for an 80% confidence region for the unknown mean vector $\mu$, you do need to use $S$, and also the axes are divided by $sqrt(n)$?

Comment: If you want a prediction region containing $X$ with a certain probability taking into account uncertainty in estimated parameters, you can probably develop something analogous to a prediction interval for $\mu$ in the univariate normal case, based on [Hotelling's T-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution)

Comment: [This answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/61993/77222) is also relevant

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assume first the the parameters $\boldsymbol\mu$ and $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ are known.  Just as $\frac{x-\mu}\sigma$ is standard normal and $\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}$ chi-square with 1 degree of freedom in the univariate case, the quadratic form
$(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)$ is chi-square with $p$ degrees of freedom when $\mathbf{x}$ is multivariate normal.  Hence, this pivot 
$$
(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)\le \chi_{p,\alpha}^2 \tag{1}
$$
with probability $(1-\alpha)$.  A probability region for $\mathbf{x}$ is found by inverting (1) with respect to $\mathbf{x}$.  For points at the boundary of this set, ${\mathbf{L}^{-1}}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})$ lies on a circle with radius $\sqrt{\chi^2_{p,\alpha}}$ where $\mathbf L$ is the cholesky factor of $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ (or some other square root) such that
$$
\mathbf{L}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol{\mu})=\sqrt{\chi^2_{p,\alpha}}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)
\end{matrix}
\right].
$$
Hence, the boundary of the set (an ellipse) is described by the parametric curve
$$
\mathbf{x}(\theta)=
\boldsymbol{\mu} + \sqrt{\chi^2_{p,\alpha}}\mathbf{L}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)
\end{matrix}
\right],
$$
for $0<\theta <2\pi$.

If the parameters are unknown and we we use $\bar{\mathbf{x}}$ to estimate $\boldsymbol\mu$, $\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}} \sim N_p(0,(1+1/n))\boldsymbol{\Sigma})$.  Hence, $(1+1/n)^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}})$ is chi-square with $p$ degrees of freedom.  Substituting $\boldsymbol\Sigma$ by its estimate $\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}=\frac1{n-1}\mathbf{X}^T \mathbf{X}$ the resulting pivot is instead [Hotelling $T$-squared distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hotelling%27s_T-squared_distribution) with $p$ and $n-p$ degrees of freedom (analogous to the $F_{1,n-1}$ distributed squared $t$-statistic in the univariate case) such that
$$
\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}})^T\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\bar{\mathbf{x}})
\le T^2_{p,n-p,\alpha} \tag{2}
$$
with probability $(1-\alpha)$.  Because the Hotelling $T$-squared is just a rescaled $F$-distribution, the above quantile equals $\frac{p(n-1)}{n-p}F_{p,n-p,\alpha}$.

Inverting (2) with respect to $\mathbf{x}$ leads to a prediction region with boundary described by the parametric curve
$$
\mathbf{x}(\theta)=
\bar{\mathbf x} + \sqrt{\Big(1+\frac1n\Big)\frac{p(n-1)}{n-p}F_{p,n-p,\alpha}}\hat{\mathbf{L}}
\left[
\begin{matrix}
\cos(\theta)\\
\sin(\theta)
\end{matrix}
\right]
$$
where $\hat{\mathbf L}$ is the cholesky factor of the sample variance matrix $\hat{\boldsymbol\Sigma}$.

Code computing this for the data in the original question:

```
pred.int.mvnorm <- function(x, alpha=.05) {
  p <- ncol(x)
  n <- nrow(x)
  Sigmahat <- var(x)
  xbar <- apply(x,2,mean)
  xbar
  theta <- seq(0, 2*pi, length=100)
  polygon <- xbar + 
    sqrt(p*(n-1)/(n-p)*(1 + 1/n)*qf(alpha, p, n - p, lower.tail = FALSE))*
    t(chol(Sigmahat)) %*% 
    rbind(cos(theta), sin(theta))
  t(polygon)
}
x <- matrix(c(-0.9,2.4,-1.4,2.9,2.0,0.2,0.7,1.0,-0.5,-1.0),ncol=2)
plot(pred.int.mvnorm(x), type="l",xlab=expression(x[1]),ylab=expression(x[2]))
points(x)
```

[image]

More code testing the coverage

```
library(mvtnorm)
library(sp)
hits <- 0
for (i in 1:1e+5) {
  x <- rmvnorm(6, sigma = diag(2))
  pred.int <- pred.int.mvnorm(x[-1,])
  x <- x[1,]
  if (point.in.polygon(x[1], x[2], pred.int[,1], pred.int[,2])==1)
    hits <- hits + 1
}
hits
[1] 94955
```