# Eigenvectors and eigenvalues of covariance matrix or its inverse in drawing ellipsoid

Tags: covariance-matrix, eigenvalues

I'm trying to draw an ellipsoid of the $3 \times 3$ covariance matrix. Usually, I see the sentence

> an ellipsoid corresponding to the eigenvectors and eigenvalues of covariance matrix.

But from the equation

$$(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)^T\boldsymbol\Sigma^{-1}(\mathbf{x}-\boldsymbol\mu)\le \chi_{p,\alpha}^2 \tag{1}$$

in this [answer](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/373988/249463), it seems to me that we do the eigen-decomposition of the inverse of covariance matrix.

Could you please elaborate on this point?

IMHO,

Let $\bar x$ and $\Sigma$ be the mean and covariance matrix of the data. Then the ellipsoid is $\{x \in \mathbb R^d | (x-\bar x)^T \Sigma(x-\bar x) = a\}$ for some $a>0$. The value of $a$ determines the confidence region. We consider the eigen-decomposition  $\Sigma = P\Lambda P^{-1} =P\Lambda P^T$. Here $\Lambda$ is the diagonal matrix generated by eigenvalues $\lambda_1, \ldots, \lambda_d$, while each column of $P$ is an eigenvector. Let $y = P^T(x - \bar x)$. Then $(x-\bar x)^T \Sigma(x-\bar x) = y^T \Lambda y = \lambda_1y_1^2+...+\lambda_d y_d^2$. Then $y = P^T(x - \bar x)$ denotes the rotation of $x - \bar x$ by $P^T$.

Comment: The eigendecomposition of $\Sigma^{-1}$ is extremely simply related to that of $\Sigma;$ using one is equivalent to using the other.

Comment: @whuber Could you please confirm if $(x-\bar x)^T \Sigma(x-\bar x) = a$ or $(x-\bar x)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\bar x) = a$ is the correct formula?

Comment: By considering the case of one dimension the answer will be immediately clear.

Comment: @whuber Thank you so much for your verification.

Comment: For the record, I'm not trying to be coy -- I'm only worried about being misunderstood or even mistakenly giving you bad information.  It really is better for you to convince yourself concerning how to proceed.

Comment: @whuber I understand that. That's really deep help. You could just write a short answer "The latter is correct", but you did much more than that.